# What is the precendence of item types within WordPress

Tags: content

I recently stumbled across an issue on a site that uses the following URL structure;

```
/%postname%/%post_id%/
```

An old blog entry had the URL www.mysite.com/my-blog-post/1918/

Since that entry was made there was some media added to the site with the name My Blog Post, meaning the slug for it was also my-blog-post.

Since the addition of the media anyone going to www.thesite.com/my-blog-post/1918/ would be shown the media page instead of the blog page.

I can't see this happening too often, I have corrected the error and informed the guys in charge of content to be mindful of it but it got me thinking about the precedence of different item types.

I would have thought off the bat that Media types would be lower down the list, but apparently not.

**What I would like to know is how I go about finding what the precendence of WordPress items is and if there is any way of changing it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precedence is determined by the order of the rewrite rules:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L196

These map the structure to a query, which is then fed to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), which has its own defaults. I don't see why you would be landing onto the media post, the `post_id` does not match, there should not be any collision in the first place. This does not appear to be undefined behavior, rather a bug in the rewrite rules, caused by some plugins or the theme etc. I assume that there's a rewrite rule at the top which makes `/pagename/.*/` fetch media post types.

Dump the rules (`var_dump( get_rewrite_rules() )`) and see if anything makes sense.

Further reading:

- http://theme.fm/2011/11/wordpress-internals-the-rewrite-api-2684/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1419